# Jersey maven skeleton project not running

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm just getting started with jersey and have built the jersey 2.0 skeleton webapp using maven.

The command being:
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.0

Now if I try to execute this using mvn clean exec:java I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testwebservice 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ testwebservice ---
[INFO] Deleting /Volumes/data/Projects/TestWebService/testwebservice/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testwebservice >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testwebservice <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ testwebservice ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.627s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Jun 22 17:46:18 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project testwebservice: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

The help provided isn't very helpful and I can't seem to find anything about this on the web. I have no clue where to set the parameters mainClass for "goal" (whatever that means) org.codehaus... . This is my first maven project and I'm pretty lost

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

You have generated a WEB Project and you are trying to run a java Application.

If you have a look at the [Exec Plungin Documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) you will find that it requires an `mainClass`argument

and that's what the error message tells you

> The parameters 'mainClass' for goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid

But as I've already written you have generated a WEB Application Skeleton running it as Java Application does not really make sense.

Have a look at [Building Simple Jersey Web App With Maven](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/building_simple_jersey_web_app) to find out what you'll have to do to get your web application running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command using command line by going inside your project directory:

```
mvn clean generate-sources package
```

Comment: Nope doesn't change anything about the error, but the war file is successfully built